# Create decision trees with pandas and scikit learn using binary matrix/occurance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data set which is actually a occurrence matrix of a feature vector for some numbers of items. In theory, this type of representation helps to apply   machine learning algorithms to data set as its normalized.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,class

1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,class1
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,class2
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,class2
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,class3
```

But I cant seem to use the algorithms provided by  pandas and scikit learning in python. I haven't seen any examples.

The format of the data set is as follows.
where feature `vector =[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]` and class variable is at the end of the file showing classes (eg:- 'class1','class2'.'class3')

How could I apply decision tree algorithms such as CART and Naive Bayes for this type of data sets? (I only checked scikit learning library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use integers for your class/dependent variable, not strings.

Here's an example:

```
In [1]: # Here I'm just mapping very simply, you can definitely use regex or something for your case if you have a lot of classes 
df['class'] = df['class'].map({'class1':0, 'class2':1, 'class3':2})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
a   b   ...     y   z   class
0   1   ...     1   1   0
1   0   ...     0   1   1
2   0   ...     0   1   1 
3   1   ...     0   1   2

In [3]: # Break between X (independent variables) and y (dependent, class)
X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df['class']

In [4]: # Now you can do your fit etc...
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
result = gnb.fit(X,y)

In [5]:
y_pred = result.predict(X)
y_pred
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

We see that it predicted correctly the class (obviously given the high number of features versus sample size (p>n)).

Comment: Thank You very much and sorry for taking so much time to reply. However, cam I gain more details about the accuracy of the predictor, folding the data set/ Can you point our some good resources to learn this?

Comment: `result.score(X,y)` will give you the accuracy of the predictor. Read the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html). Also, check out the `metrics` module [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics) to get more metrics, like Area under Roc Curve (AUC) etc

Comment: Thank You very much! I just followed the steps and read the documentation. Its really helpful. One more question, Cant this type of binary data handled by WEKA (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

Comment: Never used weka, so idk